# Select a textbox with Python Selenium, changing frame

Tags: python, selenium

**Warning: Complete Novice**

I'm trying to select the text box for the 'Login ID' on the website: 
https://www.schwab.com/public/schwab/nn/login/login.html&lang=en

I'm using Python 3.7 and Selenium. I've tried to inspect the textbox element to find the CSS Selector. This causes an error. I know I need to switch my 'frame', but I can't read the website back end coding well enough to find the right frame name.

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path, chrome_options=option)
Login_Id_TextBox = browser.find_element_by_id('LoginId')
```

Can anyone help me find the right frame or direct me to a good source to learning more about them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send a *character sequence* with in the text box for the *Login ID* on the website https://www.schwab.com/public/schwab/nn/login/login.html&lang=en as the the desired element is within an `<iframe>` so you have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it()`.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired `element_to_be_clickable()`.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - `CSS_SELECTOR`:

    ```
    driver.get('https://www.schwab.com/public/schwab/nn/login/login.html&lang=en')
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe#loginIframe")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.form-control#LoginId"))).send_keys("averagejoe1080")
    ```
  - `XPATH`:

    ```
    driver.get('https://www.schwab.com/public/schwab/nn/login/login.html&lang=en')
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@id='loginIframe']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='form-control' and @id='LoginId']"))).send_keys("averagejoe1080")
    ```

> Here you can find a relevant discussion on [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simple code for your requirement, I test this successfully.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.schwab.com/public/schwab/nn/login/login.html&lang=en')
driver.switch_to_frame("loginIframe")
Login_Id_TextBox = driver.find_element_by_id('LoginId')
```